# htaccess block every IP/visitor and bots except google bot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am learning htaccess. Is the following possible by using htaccess:

1) Block every visitor/IP to site.

2) Block all the bots except google bot.

```
RewriteEngine On
order deny,allow
deny from all

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bingbot|Baiduspider) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

Is the above htaccess right? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `bingbot` and `Baiduspider` certainly do _not_ somehow refer to "the google bot", you have to reverse your logic here. Apart from that keep in mind that it is trivial to forge such headers by anyone, so anyone can access the resources without an issue.

Comment: I am beginner with htaccess. Is it possible what I am trying to achieve using htaccess. Can you guide me or give me any useful link? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is the above htaccess right?

No, of course it isn’t right – because you are blocking *all* requests with

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

– so the Google bot won’t get access either.

You can do this by using a combination of `SetEnvIf` and `Allow` – see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#allow, that has an example for exactly this.

(You’ll need to remove the `Directory` directive used in there, because that can’t be used in .htaccess files. But only those two lines, what is *inside* the directive you have to keep of course.)